# Method Not Importing

Tags: java, methods

This may be simple, but I'm new. I have this method in a class of a different package. I import the class containing the below method into the class where I need to use it, but I can't use it, it always errors and asks me to create it in the class that I imported it into.

```
public static int getRandom(int min, int max){ 
        int randomNum = RNG.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        return randomNum;
    }
```

If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Can you please post the details of the error you are getting?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] of this. I would guess the import is wrong (unlikely with this message), the method is not static, or the parameter are incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean , you have defined a method in A class, like :

```
class A{
      public static int getRandom(int min, int max){ 
        int randomNum = RNG.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        return randomNum;
    }
}
```

and you want to import it into another class like

```
class B{

}
```

then you must have to call it like:

```
A.getRandom(minValue, maxValue)
```

since it's a static method , you have to call it by class name.

Comment: That's a supposition as the error is not clearly explain, the code is where the error is or the method called ?

Comment: what is the error ? does it is the same class structure that i have mentioned ??